# Mobile Safari iOS failing to load multiple small files (such as images or JavaScript) on first page visit only

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, loading

I've been fighting a problem on the iPhone and iPad where it fails to load multiple assets at the same time. Two scenarios:

a) Loading approx 20+ external JavaScript files - this is not a problem on my live sites because I combine my JavaScript into one file before deploying, but causes issues on my test server.

b) Loading approx. 20+ small thumbnail images on the same page (each one is roughly 30kb).

In both scenarios Safari (usually) gets stuck on a handful of files and never finishes loading them. The loading indicator on the iOS top menu is stuck loading until a refresh.

The second time you visit (when the assets are cached) all will be fine. I have to clear Safari's cache to reproduce the issue.

I can get round the issue by delaying load of the assets in JavaScript, but this is quite bodgy and I'd like to better understand what's going wrong and see if I can find a neater solution.

An example can be seen here (visit on an iOS device): http://www.jamesgretton.co.uk/expem/so_ios_multi/

Also, in case it's useful, I've got round the problem here by delaying the load of the thumbnails: http://www.interior-id.com/work/ but it would break otherwise.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

James

Comment: I've just earned a stackoverflow "tumbleweed" award for this post. Not quite the plan! Interestingly I've since noticed this on other sites on iOS, so I do think it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues of the same kind on my test server, and it was related to the Basic Auth password configuration. As soon as we removed the Authentication headers, Mobile Safari was loading all files as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with IOS Safari and for some reason it didn't like  "use strict"; at the top of one of my javascript files.  Very annoying to work this out but removing it seems to have fixed the issue!

Comment: Interesting; it wasn't a "use strict" problem for me when this was going wrong (back in iOS 6 I think), but when I try it now (iOS 9.0) my example link loads fine - perhaps it would go wrong again if I added use strict!